# I can't uninstall Homebrew. How can I find and remove all of my Homebrew files and re-install it again?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, homebrew, javascript

I've deleted a main Homebrew file and now I can't un-install Homebrew. I want to un-install it and then do a fresh install. This is what I'm getting in the Terminal...

```
host:~ user$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you should do the following before running this installer again: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
host:~ user$  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

I'm bit of a rookie as you can probably tell. How can I sort this?

The main goal is to set up the MEAN stack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you move things or rename directories used by homebrew? Try locating with `gem search ^homebrew` or `gem list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Uninstall Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew)

From the Homebrew FAQ:

> To uninstall Homebrew, paste the command below in a terminal prompt.
>
> ```
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
> ```

Comment: What happens when you put in that command above and get this:
Failed to locate Homebrew!

Comment: @Katherine please can you ask this as a new question; see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask